# React.js Bootstrap Add or Remove Input Fields

Tags: javascript, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm building a web app using `React.js` and `react-bootstrap`. I have a form page where the user can type in symptoms of a disease that they are experiencing. I want the user to be able to type in text and also have the option to remove previously typed text.

An example of it being done in Javascript is here:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove-bs3

I would like to have the same feature as the link above but using React. Here's the code I have so far for the section, but I'm unsure of the best way to continue.

```
var closeButton = <Button onClick={this.removeSymptomField()}>Close</Button>;

<Input type="text" buttonAfter={closeButton} placeholder="Type a symptom here."/>

<Button onClick={this.addSymptomField()}>Click to add a new symptom.</Button>
```

When `this.addSymptomField()` is called, I want to add an `Input` field to the page, and when `this.removeSymptomField()` is called, I want to remove the existing `Input` field from the page.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a list of current inputs in state and modify that when calling `addSymptomField` and `removeSymptomField`

In your component constructor

```
this.state = { inputs: [] }
```

In render

```
<div className="inputs">
   {this.renderInputs()}
</div>
```

And your renderInputs method could look like this

```
renderInputs() {
   return this.state.inputs.map((input, index) => <Input key={index} type="text" buttonAfter={closeButton} placeholder="Type a symptom here."/>)
}
```

Then simply add or remove inputs to/from the list when calling the `addSymptomField` and `removeSymptomField` methods

Comment: this is great and very lightweight, thank you so much!

Comment: I know how the add button function would look like. 

But how would the remove function look like if this was my add field function: 


  appendInput() {
    var newInput = `input-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
    this.setState({ inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([newInput]) });
  }